# Higher direct image of morphism with generic fiber $\mathbb{P}^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

Let $f:X\to Y$ be the morphism of smooth varieties over $\mathbb{C}$ with generic fiber equal to $\mathbb{P}^1$. How to prove that $R^if_*\mathcal{O}_X=0$ for $i>0$?

(I do not need the complete solution, just an idea)

Comment: Doesn't this work by proving the vanishing stalkwise?

Comment: It's possible that [this lemma from the Stacks Project](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02KH) might help. I was able to use it to prove that all the higher direct images are at least torsion irrespective of  whether $X$ or $Y$ is smooth, but I don't know if that will help.

Comment: Looks to me to be an application of cohomology and base change.

Comment: If $X=Y\times\mathbb{P}^1$ then indeed it is easy to deduce this from the flat base change formula. But why is it true in general case?

Comment: @vitaliy maybe there's a way to reduce the problem to that case.

Comment: Please correct me if i'm wrong, but how about the following attempt: Denoting the generic point of $Y$ by $\eta_Y$, cohomology and base change yields that $(R^if_{\ast}\mathcal{O}_X)\vert_{\eta_Y}=0$ for $i>0$. But as $R^if_{\ast}\mathcal{O}_X$ is quasicoherent on $Y$, its rank is upper-semicontinuous, so $(R^if_{\ast}\mathcal{O}_X)\vert_{y}=0$ for $i>0$ for every $y$ in $Y$, and hence $R^if_{\ast}\mathcal{O}_X=0$ for $i>0$?

Comment: @user178979 I think the problem with this argument is that rank is only upper-semicontinuous for coherent sheaves. IIRC the proof uses Nakayama's Lemma.

Comment: @user178979: leaving aside the issue of coherent versus quasicoherent, you've got your semicontinuity the wrong way round. _Upper semicontinuous_ means the value can "jump up" at special points. So a coherent sheaf whose stalk is zero at the generic point need not be the zero sheaf!

Comment: So what is the right way to think about?

Comment: @Relapsarian: Hm, i didn't think this through - thank you for correcting me!

Comment: @BenLim: You're right - thank you for pointing this out to me!

Comment: I asked this question on [MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/210550/vanishing-of-higher-direct-image-of-a-morphism-with-generic-fiber-bbbp1)